# Wubi installation problem

Tags: system-installation, wubi

When I try installing Ubuntu with the Wubi installer I get this message

```
An error occurred
Permission denied
For more information, please see the log file: (written below post)
```

I also tried installing from boot DVD, but after I choose to either try Ubuntu without installing or installing the screen just goes black and nothing happens.

I tried with the latest versions of Ubuntu 64-bit. I'm currently running Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit.

Log file:

```
09-28 13:21 INFO   root: === wubi 13.04 rev279 ===
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  root: Logfile is c:\users\fnatmi~1\appdata\local\temp\wubi-13.04-rev279.log
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  root: sys.argv = ['main.pyo', '--exefile="G:\\wubi.exe"']
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  CommonBackend: data_dir=C:\Users\FNATMI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pylBA69.tmp\data
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: 7z=C:\Users\FNATMI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pylBA69.tmp\bin\7z.exe
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: startup_folder=C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Fetching basic info...
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  CommonBackend: original_exe=G:\wubi.exe
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  CommonBackend: platform=win32
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  CommonBackend: osname=nt
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  CommonBackend: language=da_DK
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  CommonBackend: encoding=cp1252
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: arch=amd64
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Parsing isolist=C:\Users\FNATMI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pylBA69.tmp\data\isolist.ini
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Edubuntu-i386
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Kubuntu-amd64
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Mythbuntu-i386
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Edubuntu-amd64
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Ubuntu Studio-amd64
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Ubuntu-amd64
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Lubuntu-i386
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Ubuntu-i386
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Mythbuntu-amd64
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Kubuntu-i386
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Ubuntu Studio-i386
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Lubuntu-amd64
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: Fetching host info...
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: registry_key=Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Wubi
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: windows version=vista
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: windows_version2=Windows 7 Home Premium
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: windows_sp=None
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: windows_build=7601
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: gmt=1
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: country=DK
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: timezone=Europe/Copenhagen
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: windows_username=Fnatmiden
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: user_full_name=Fnatmiden
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: user_directory=C:\Users\Fnatmiden
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: windows_language_code=1030
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: windows_language=Danish
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: processor_name=Intel(R) Core(TM) i7 CPU       Q 720  @ 1.60GHz
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: bootloader=vista
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: system_drive=Drive(C: hd 18025.890625 mb free ntfs)
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: drive=Drive(C: hd 18025.890625 mb free ntfs)
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: drive=Drive(D: hd 1024.0 mb free ntfs)
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: drive=Drive(E: hd 87.93359375 mb free fat32)
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: drive=Drive(F: cd 0.0 mb free udf)
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: drive=Drive(G: cd 0.0 mb free cdfs)
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: uninstaller_path=None
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: previous_target_dir=None
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: previous_distro_name=None
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: keyboard_id=67503110
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: keyboard_layout=dk
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: keyboard_variant=
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  CommonBackend: python locale=('da_DK', 'cp1252')
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  CommonBackend: locale=da_DK.UTF-8
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: total_memory_mb=4086.86328125
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Searching ISOs on USB devices
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Searching for local CDs
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\FNATMI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pylBA69.tmp is a valid Ubuntu CD
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\FNATMI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pylBA69.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\FNATMI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pylBA69.tmp is a valid Ubuntu CD
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\FNATMI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pylBA69.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\FNATMI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pylBA69.tmp is a valid Kubuntu CD
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\FNATMI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pylBA69.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\FNATMI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pylBA69.tmp is a valid Kubuntu CD
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\FNATMI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pylBA69.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\FNATMI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pylBA69.tmp is a valid Mythbuntu CD
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\FNATMI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pylBA69.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\FNATMI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pylBA69.tmp is a valid Mythbuntu CD
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\FNATMI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pylBA69.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\FNATMI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pylBA69.tmp is a valid Edubuntu CD
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\FNATMI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pylBA69.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\FNATMI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pylBA69.tmp is a valid Edubuntu CD
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\FNATMI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pylBA69.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\FNATMI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pylBA69.tmp is a valid Lubuntu CD
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\FNATMI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pylBA69.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\FNATMI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pylBA69.tmp is a valid Lubuntu CD
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\FNATMI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pylBA69.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\FNATMI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pylBA69.tmp is a valid Ubuntu Studio CD
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\FNATMI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pylBA69.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\FNATMI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pylBA69.tmp is a valid Ubuntu Studio CD
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\FNATMI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pylBA69.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether D:\ is a valid Ubuntu CD
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain D:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether D:\ is a valid Ubuntu CD
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain D:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether D:\ is a valid Kubuntu CD
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain D:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether D:\ is a valid Kubuntu CD
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain D:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether D:\ is a valid Mythbuntu CD
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain D:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether D:\ is a valid Mythbuntu CD
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain D:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether D:\ is a valid Edubuntu CD
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain D:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether D:\ is a valid Edubuntu CD
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain D:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether D:\ is a valid Lubuntu CD
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain D:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether D:\ is a valid Lubuntu CD
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain D:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether D:\ is a valid Ubuntu Studio CD
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain D:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether D:\ is a valid Ubuntu Studio CD
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain D:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether E:\ is a valid Ubuntu CD
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain E:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether E:\ is a valid Ubuntu CD
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain E:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether E:\ is a valid Kubuntu CD
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain E:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether E:\ is a valid Kubuntu CD
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain E:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether E:\ is a valid Mythbuntu CD
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain E:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether E:\ is a valid Mythbuntu CD
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain E:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether E:\ is a valid Edubuntu CD
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain E:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether E:\ is a valid Edubuntu CD
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain E:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether E:\ is a valid Lubuntu CD
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain E:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether E:\ is a valid Lubuntu CD
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain E:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether E:\ is a valid Ubuntu Studio CD
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain E:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether E:\ is a valid Ubuntu Studio CD
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain E:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether F:\ is a valid Ubuntu CD
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain F:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether F:\ is a valid Ubuntu CD
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain F:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether F:\ is a valid Kubuntu CD
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain F:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether F:\ is a valid Kubuntu CD
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain F:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether F:\ is a valid Mythbuntu CD
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain F:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether F:\ is a valid Mythbuntu CD
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain F:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether F:\ is a valid Edubuntu CD
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain F:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether F:\ is a valid Edubuntu CD
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain F:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether F:\ is a valid Lubuntu CD
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain F:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether F:\ is a valid Lubuntu CD
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain F:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether F:\ is a valid Ubuntu Studio CD
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain F:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether F:\ is a valid Ubuntu Studio CD
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain F:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether G:\ is a valid Ubuntu CD
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain G:\casper\vmlinuz.efi
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether G:\ is a valid Ubuntu CD
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  Distro:   parsing info from str=Ubuntu 13.04 "Raring Ringtail" - Release i386 (20130424)
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  Distro:   parsed info={'name': 'Ubuntu', 'subversion': 'Release', 'version': '13.04', 'build': '20130424', 'codename': 'Raring Ringtail', 'arch': 'i386'}
09-28 13:21 INFO   Distro: Found a valid CD for Ubuntu: G:\
09-28 13:21 INFO   root: Running the CD menu...
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  WindowsFrontend: __init__...
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  WindowsFrontend: on_init...
09-28 13:21 INFO   WinuiPage: appname=wubi, localedir=C:\Users\FNATMI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pylBA69.tmp\translations, languages=['da_DK', 'da']
09-28 13:21 INFO   WinuiPage: appname=wubi, localedir=C:\Users\FNATMI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pylBA69.tmp\translations, languages=['da_DK', 'da']
09-28 13:21 INFO   root: CD menu finished
09-28 13:21 INFO   root: Rebooting
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  TaskList: # Running tasklist...
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Running reboot...
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Finished reboot
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  TaskList: # Finished tasklist
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  root: application.quit
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  WindowsFrontend: frontend.quit
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  WindowsFrontend: frontend.on_quit
09-28 13:21 DEBUG  root: application.on_quit
09-28 13:21 INFO   root: sys.exit
```

Answer (score 2):

You're getting your error message because you're trying to install Ubuntu 13.04 using Wubi and Ubuntu 13.04 does not support Wubi. However the Long Term Support version of Ubuntu, Ubuntu 12.04, does support Wubi. Ubuntu 12.04 is supported by updates until April, 2017.

For more information about installing Ubuntu from within Windows using Wubi visit the [Ubuntu Wubi Installation Instructions](https://web.archive.org/web/20130906083043/http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-with-windows). This is an illustrated seven-step tutorial about how to install Ubuntu with the Wubi Windows installer.

Before you install Ubuntu you should think about what type of installation, whether it is using Wubi or else a dual boot installation of Ubuntu alongside Windows 7, would be most suitable for you. This will help you to focus on learning more about what type of installation you have decided upon before you commit yourself to doing the installation.

In particular, for more information about solving the black screen problem that you got when trying to install Ubuntu from the DVD, take a look at the answers to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it).

Comment: While technically, Ubuntu 13.04 does not support Wubi (it was announced in the Release notes and all), a working `wubi.exe` was shipped with it. So it does in fact work the same as all previous releases. 12.04 is the only one advertised on the main http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-with-windows site (where it also erroneously states that it is not available)